# Requirements for bridging LAN over WLAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I need to connect a rear to a front house, cable is not possible.

The front house has a Cisco WRVS4400n router, providing 2 SSIDs - `SSID1` in `VLAN1` and `SSID2` in `VLAN99`.

The rear house now needs `VLAN1` for an IP-Camera connected to LAN and should repeat `SSID2` for public access securely separated from `VLAN1`.

Besides the router there is a Cisco WAP4410n available for the rear house.

I can't figure out how to accomplish this without buying additional hardware or using workarounds like firewalls. The information i found about WDS bridging, repeating and client modes aren't clear to me.

- What is **WDS bridging** used for? The manual says:

  > Select to let the access point operate as a 
  >   wireless bridge to perform transparent bridging with other associated 
  >   wireless bridges, and not allow any wireless client or station to access 
  >   them.

  So what does the bridge actually do? Is just can't think of a useful scenario...
- In **WDS Repeater Mode** i can not create multiple SSIDs or configure the AP to repeat multiple SSIDs, is this a limitation of the WAP4410n or is it impossible / rare? From the manual:

  > Select to let the access point operate as a 
  >   wireless repeater to extend the radio range of the associated remote 
  >   access point to overcome any obstacle that blocks radio communication.
- What is the use of an AP's LAN-Port in **WDS Repeater mode**?
- Which mode / setup would be the best practice for this case?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a WDS bridge is what you want. A WDS bridge is basically a transparent wireless bridge between two wired networks. Make sure to enable WDS on both ends.